# Proposition translation regarding "there exists" with conditional

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

How do I translate the following into English? 
$$ 1. \quad \forall x (Ax \land Bx)$$
$$ 2. \quad \forall x (Ax \to Bx)$$
$$ 3. \quad \exists x (Ax \land Bx)$$
$$ 4. \quad \exists x (Ax \to Bx)$$

1. Everyone are both A and B.
2. Every A are B.
3. Someone is A and B.
4. ... ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal translation of the fourth one is 'There exists someting such that if it is an A, then it is a B'

However, that is a very awkward sentence (and indeed the reason why you'll rarely see a conditional after an existential).

To make a little more sense of the fourth one, you could rewrite it as its logical equivalent:

$\exists x (\neg A(x) \lor B(x))$

which translates as a somewhat more meaningful 'There is something that is either not an A, or it is a B$'

Still awkward ...